# How can I view embedded images in Outlook 2011 for Mac

Tags: email, images, microsoft-outlook-2011, osx-el-capitan

Whenever I receive mails with embedded images it doesn't display the image inline, but as an attachment instead.

[image]

I am running El Capitan with Outlook 2011

[image]

I can view the images when opening the attachments it comes as, but I want them to be displayed in the email body.